# Predict the amount of occorences of a string in an unknown text

Tags: deep-learning, prediction

I started to learn about deep learning and i wanted to try a little project.
I want to try and predict the amount of time a string will appear in a book based on a data set of many words and phrases and the amount of times they appeared in other books from the same series (assuming all the books are about the same length).
I am trying to do this for a few days now and i seem to be lost, i have no idea how to do something like that and what model to use. maybe deep learning is not the method for that and i just have a tunnel vision?
Any ideas on how to approach this kind of problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have thousands of books in a series, DL is probably not the best idea. It looks more like a good exercise to understand basics of statistics/probability theory. You are looking for a conditional model `P(word|book series)` (notice that if you divide number of word occurrences by the book length you do get a probability estimate). Compute this quantity for a given book series, and you have first model to answer your question.

Comment: I thought about using statistics but i would like to try and predict the amount of occurrences for words i know nothing about but they are a part of a phrase or a combination of word that i do know about.
I do have a set of a few thousand words and phrases and their occurrences for each book in the series, is there something i can do with that?

Comment: If we are talking about unknown words, then it is a different story, but it is still a bit ill defined thing. If you never encounter word during training you cannot ask about it in testing, there is no way to infer anything about it. You need to provide some context, so that model can at least infer in what contexts this word is used etc. So you probably could try something like [train on text without word x][ train on a small chunk of text with x ][ask about x in the full document ].

Comment: Sorry that it took me a long time to replay, i just had a busy week but i really appreciate your help! I was actually thinking about creating an RNN that run on characters from each word and compares the output of the final iteration of each word to the amount of occurrences in the texts. Do you think it is something that can bring any results?